# How to also delete my class object from a list when calling __del__ function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to work again on all python basics but I can't understund something with the `__del__` function.
When i'm removing an object calling the `__del__` function, I want to delete the object aswell in a list of my class.

Here is my code, I've tried different things but I think i'm not understunding well how it works.

```py
class Player():
    players = []

    def __init__(self, pseudo):
        self.pseudo = pseudo
        self.score = 0
        self.players.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Pseudo : {} , Score : {}'.format(self.pseudo, self.score))

    def __del__(self):
        ##How can I remove the player from my player's list ? 
        Player.players.remove(self)
        print("Player has been removed.")
```

Comment: If your object is in `Player.players`, it's still reachable - `__del__` won't be called until it's unreachable.

Comment: The `Player` class should not be responsible for managing the `players` list. That kind of class-managed global instance list is a newbie trap that people fall into because they're not familiar with better designs. Similarly, `__del__` shouldn't be responsible for removing your object from data structures tracking it.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, i'm a bit lost with how to manage list / class objects, really looking for how to do it right.

Comment: @Matthieu almost certainly, you have no good reason to implement `__del__`. How do you expect it to work? In any case, fundamentally, your problem seems to be you have designed your class to implicitly add to a list every time a player is instantiated. I have a lot of reservations about this approach. Instead, you should explicitly handle whatever container you need for `Player` objects. In any case, `Player.players.remove(self)` is exactly how you *would* do what you are asking. The issue is, `__del__` would never be called in the first place

Comment: Yes, I see that list is definitely not the good way. I'm programming a small game with 100 players, I was just looking for a way to delete a player

Comment: No, a list is fine, but putting it in the `Player` class is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of managing your players list and deleting reference of the instance in it, you should use `weakref`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

> A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else. However, until the object is actually destroyed the weak reference may return the object even if there are no strong references to it.

Your `Player.players` is a list of instances of Player. If you delete the object, the list will keep the instance alive. This list should contains only weakref. This will allow you to access all the instances of the class without preventing deletion of this instances:

```py
class Player():
    players = []

    def __init__(self, pseudo):
        ...
        self.players.append(weakref.ref(self))
```

In order to access the object referenced by a weakref, you just have to call the weakref:

```py
import weakref


class Player:
    __players = []

    def __init__(self, pseudo):
        self.pseudo = pseudo
        self.score = 0
        self.__players.append(weakref.ref(self))

    @classmethod
    def players(cls):
        for player_ref in cls.__players:
            yield player_ref()

    @classmethod
    def clean_players(cls):
        for player_ref in cls.__players:
            if player_ref() is None:
                cls.__players.remove(player_ref)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Pseudo : {} , Score : {}'.format(self.pseudo, self.score))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Player object: "{self.__str__()}"'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    marvin = Player("Marvin")
    jack = Player("Jack")
    print(list(Player.players()))
    # [Player object: "Pseudo : Marvin , Score : 0", Player object: "Pseudo : Jack , Score : 0"]
    del jack
    print(list(Player.players()))
    # [Player object: "Pseudo : Marvin , Score : 0", None]
    Player.clean_players()
    print(list(Player.players()))
    # [Player object: "Pseudo : Marvin , Score : 0"]
```

Comment: While this technically stops the `Player.players` list from keeping instances alive, now you have new problems. `Player` instances are likely to die prematurely unless there's some other data structure keeping track of them, but if there is some other data structure, `Player.players` is redundant. (Also, the list will accumulate dead weakrefs.)

Comment: Making `players` a property is a bad idea - now, for no good reason, you need to access it through an existing instance of `Player`. Also, you're not handling dead references, so you'll get `None`s for dead players.

Comment: Thanks, never heard before of those weakref, need to understund the documentation... What is the goal of the `__repr__` function here compared to `__str__` ?

Comment: If he can use `del my_player`, I suppose he have ref to those objects. And if the list accumulate dead weakrefs, it can be cleaned somewhere.

Comment: @Matthieu the `__repr__` is for printing list of players. It will print `[Player object: "Pseudo : Marvin , Score : 0"]` instead of `[<__main__.Player object at 0x000001DB69B02708>]`